# Check a IList changed?

Tags: c#

I am trying to make an appointment book in Silverlight with C#, so I will have a main `AppointmentBook` control, with follows to store each of the `Appointment` control:

```
    List<kAppointment> appointments = null;

    public IList<kAppointment> Appointments
    {
        get
        {
            if (appointments == null)
            {
                appointments = new List<kAppointment>();
            }

            // Can notify something change here, 
            return appointments;
        }
    }
```

I can notify the `AppointmentBook` control new list assigned with above code, so it will redraw each of the appointments control.

But how can I check it if the appointment list is changed by the follows?:

```
appointments.Add(NewAppointment);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like a job for [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx).

This lets us subscribe to events and tells us in what way the collection changed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use and `ObservableCollection` like the others suggest or you can do some encapsulation and *not provide complete access to a private member*.

If the `Add` is done through a single public method that you provide you will always know when users of the class are adding appointments and act accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a few things.

1. Make a wrapperclass for the IList that contains an extra boolean changed.
2. Use some variable (a boolean for instance) that you make true when you do an add/remove/edit action, and make it false again when you did the redraw.
3. Keep a copy of the list your're drawing (or only of some index that are present) and check if the 'incoming' and 'last drawed' list are the same
4. Use an ObservableCollection